# AES256 encryption and decryption in ASP

Tags: asp.net, ios, encryption, key

I have to send a username and password from my iphone app to a ASP server page, and I will encrypt them using: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/strong-encryption-for-cocoa-cocoa-touch.html. What is the best way to decrypt these strings on the ASP page? I found some examples, but since the encryption will happen on two completely unrelated sides, I think I need to hard code the key in on both sides, and I can't find any examples that don't have use generated keys.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, key management is a big problem.  You will have to have the keys on both sides, on iOS you can save the key in the Keychain, that is secure but the process to get it there securely is more difficult.

The other main issue is getting all the parameters the same on both sides.  Of particular interest are

1. encryption key value and size
2. mode: CBC, ECB, etc. (you should probably be using CBC)
3. initialization vector (iv) is needed for most modes
4. padding method: PKCS7, etc. (AES is a block cypher and needs input
   in a multiple of block size)

Comment: Thanks - do you have any suggestions on how to deal with these issues?

Comment: As a start chose simple test data, get that working and move into more complex situations. Ex: initially choose an iv of all 0, CBC, data of exactly one block size with no padding. When that is working start adding in more complexity.  In any event, if you want real security have you code review by a seasoned  professional, I do.

Security is not easy, the encryption part is the easy part.

Or use SSL.  Oh, accept answers if they are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the passwords in the database with SHA1, then use HMAC with a client specified key for the communication?

Have the server generate a random key and send it with the login request. The client computes the SHA1 hash of the password, then computes the HMAC SHA1 hash of that using the server-specified key. The server then verifies that the result is correct.

On the client end:

```
// password is the plaintext password
// keyb64 is a random key specified by the server, encoded in base64.
string ComputeSecureHash(string password, string keyb64)
{
    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
    byte[] key = Convert.FromBase64String(keyb64);
    byte[] hash;
    byte[] machash;
    // compute a plain SHA1 hash of the specified data
    using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
    {
        hash = sha1.ComputeHash(data);
    }
    // now compute a HMAC hash of that hash, using the random key.
    using (HMACSHA1 sha1mac = new HMACSHA1(key))
    {
        machash = sha1mac.ComputeHash(hash);
    }
    return Convert.ToBase64String(machash);
}
```

On the server end:

```
// hash is the string produced by the function above
// realHash is the SHA1 hash of the real password, which you've fetched from the db
// key is the key you generated for this login session
bool VerifyHash(string hash, byte[] realHash, byte[] key)
{
    byte[] machash;
    using (HMACSHA1 sha1mac = new HMACSHA1(key))
    {
        machash = sha1mac.ComputeHash(realHash);
    }
    return (Convert.ToBase64String(machash) == hash);
}
```

This allows you to authenticate over a plaintext medium without having the password cracked.

Comment: Rolling your own scheme tends to end in tears.  Most developers are better off sticking with a tried and true technology like TLS / SSL.

Comment: This isn't "my own scheme", it's a well known form of MAC authentication.

Comment: I realize that, but it's authenticating the client, not the server.  This scheme doesn't prevent MITM, for example.  Technologies like TLS do, hence the earlier recommendation.

Comment: How does it not prevent MITM? It's a server-chosen key, which prevents replay attacks. You can't decrypt the password, either. Sure you could go and attack the session after it's authenticated, but that's not what the question asked to prevent.